# Disabling authoring information in Omega 3.x does not work from content type; how can I disable it?

Tags: 7, theming

I see no way of successfully disabling, through the user interface, the author information, wheb using an Omega 3.x sub-theme. The standard method of disabling it from the content type settings is not functional.

So is my only option to use a theme suggestion?

Comment: If this was a bug, I believe it is now fixed, because I am able to turn off the display of author information using the checkbox in the content type settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how exactly it looks in your Omega theme, but in Zen you just remove/change the following snippet in templates/node.tpl.php (or templates/node--content_type.tpl.php):

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In Bartik it's equivalent would be:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="meta submitted">
    <?php print $user_picture; ?>
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej,
But what im trying to find is a way to make it work without needing the "theme suggest".  I am aware of this method, but because i am trying to build a replicatable template, i need this setting stored in the dB somewhere.  I believe this is an issue with the Omega theme not having conditional logic for the $submitted value.  While all other themes seem to have this.  I will take it up with the dev, to make this an option in the Omega settings or to use the Content Type configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Well in omega you can still disable author and date in your content-type settings, but what if you only want to disable one portion of it? for example just the author name? go ahead and copy **node.tpl.php** from omega > templates folder into your subtheme folder then find this part:

```
      <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
       <footer class="submitted"><?php print $date; ?> -- <?php print $name; ?>   </footer>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

as you can see in omega unlike other themes it renders as two different variables: $date and $name . so you can delete `<?php print $name; ?>` or `<?php print $date; ?>`

make sure after copying **node.tpl.php** empty your cache.